# Saving a Hexagon Grid to a file

Tags: java, file, libgdx

I am making a small library to work with LibGDX, to make a hexagonal grid. It is coming along nicely(I have gotten a lot done with it), but one feature that I have not been able to figure out is to have the map saved to a file. I don't really want it to be a large file, but I want it to be able to save all the X, Y, Z, with the instance of the hexagon(I made the hexagon in Wings3D, so I could more easily add colors and stuff). I am just wanting some suggestions and what not to make it as small as possible, but still holding all the information. Thank you for your time :)

**EDIT**

So I need it to save something like this:
`1,5,2: grass` where the 1 is X, 5 is Y and so on, And then the "grass" is the file of the obj. I don't know if I should do JSON, or what, but I want it also illiterate-able.

**EDIT 2**

So I have been playing around with a JSON formatter, and found that this code works:

```
{"map":[[1,5,2,"grass"], [4,2,5,"blue"]]}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, or do you think that that is a very efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you made your object in Wings3d, I assume that it's an obj file or similar format and your program displays many instances of them. If so, you only need to save the information necessary to position the objects (e.g. coordinate and any other transformations). That could be as simple as series of numbers (separated by commas) for each object, with one object per line.

Then your program could simply read each line, split the string and create the hexes based on the data.